# Does xlwings only work with the first instance of Excel?

Tags: python, xlwings

Is this a known limitation that will be addressed at some point, or is this just something that I need to accept?

If this is not possible with xlwings, I wonder if any of the other alternatives out there supports connecting to other instances.

I'm specifically talking about the scenario where you are calling python from within Excel, so the hope is that the getCaller() function will be able to figure out which instance of the Excel is actually calling it.

Comment: the first question is: do you really work with various instances when you get that error message?

Comment: Yes, I work with many heavy excel instances, and having too many files open in one instance tends to freeze and crash excel.

Comment: Using multiple instances also have the benefit that if one misbehaves, i can kill it in one instance without affecting the others. this of course is on top of the more general benefit of being able to lay multiple Excel windows  out on my multi-monitor setup. (Thanks a lot for your help by the way. Great utility you've created here!)

Comment: Ok, then on to the second question: Are your files stored on some network drives?

Comment: Yes, stored on a S drive mapped to a network location.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on your comments I think I can answer your question: Actually, yes, xlwings can handle various instances. But workbooks from untrusted locations (like downloaded from the internet or sometimes on shared network drives) don't play nicely.
So in your case you could try to add the network location to `File > Options > Trust Center >  Trust Center Settings... > Trusted Locations` or, under `Trusted Documents`, tick the checkbox `Allow documents on a network to be trusted`.
If you don't have the previlegies to change these options, then I guess you're left with the options of running the tools locally or indeed, open them in the 1st instance...

Comment: Great to know. Will this be a per-file setting or an Excel setting?

Comment: These are Excel settings. So did it actually work then?

Comment: Not yet. :(
  File "S:\factorAnalyzer.py", line 148, in doCalc
    wb = Workbook.caller()
  File "C:\Users\rfang\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 182, in caller
    xl_workbook = xlplatform.get_xl_workbook_from_xl(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\rfang\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 433, in get_xl_workbook_from_xl
    raise Exception("Can't establish connection! "
Exception: Can't establish connection! Make sure that the calling workbook is the active one and is opened in the first instance of Excel.

Comment: If you're saying it *should* work, then I'll keep looking at what might be wrong, but of course greatly appreciate any pointers you might have.

Comment: I need to try it out later, but you might want to unaccept the answer until it really works ;-)

Comment: haha. ok. but i trusted you!    I'm sure you'll have an answer i can accept soon. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: once this issue is implemented, it might actually solve your problem without tinkering with the settings: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/30